# How to set the value of a JSpinner using a LocalTime object?

Tags: java, swing, datetime, localtime, jspinner

I am trying to make a time picker using JSpinner and Java 8's time API. I want to make a time picker without date.

Before, I was using SimpleDateFormat, but that would return time with date when I print out the value of the JSpinner.

So how can I pass the value of a LocalTime object into the setValue method of a JSpinner?

Here is my current code:

```
JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm");
timeSpinner.setEditor(timeEditor);
LocalTime newTime = LocalTime.of(11, 9);
timeSpinner.setValue(newTime);
        
timeSpinner.setBounds(126, 55, 56, 22);
contentPanel.add(timeSpinner);
```

Or am I taking the wrong approach to this?

This is my original code which works:

```
JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm");
timeSpinner.setEditor(timeEditor);
SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
    timeSpinner.setValue(time.parseObject("10:00"));
} catch (ParseException timeError) {
    timeError.printStackTrace();
}
timeSpinner.setBounds(126, 55, 56, 22);
contentPanel.add(timeSpinner);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: SpinnerDateModel only works with java.util.Date values.  If you want the time portion of a Date value, use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) to extract the individual fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, method `getValue()`, of class `SpinnerDateModel`, returns an instance of `java.util.Date()` but you can convert that into a `LocalTime` as follows:

```java
Object obj = timeSpinner.getValue();
if (obj instanceof java.util.Date) {
    java.util.Date theDate = (java.util.Date) obj;
    java.time.Instant inst = theDate.toInstant();
    java.time.ZoneId theZone = java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault();
    java.time.LocalTime thetime = java.time.LocalTime.ofInstant(inst, theZone); // Since JDK 9
    /*
    LocalTime.from(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(inst, theZone)); // Since JDK 8
     */
    System.out.println(thetime);
}
```

As you can see, there are two ways to convert `java.util.Date` to `LocalTime`, depending on which JDK version you are using.

The above code will print `theTime` in format `HH:mm`